# How can I programmatically read server logs from HLDS?

Tags: c#, php, udp

How does one go about reading and parsing server logs sent remotely from HLDS (Half-Life Dedicated Server)?

My understanding is that you can specify where the server delivers logs using the command `log_address`.  After this, the server is supposed to deliver the logs via UDP.

How can I go about listening for these logs with either PHP or ASP.NET C#?  I don't know if I'm supposed to be listening for incoming packets, or send a request to HLDS for packets.  I've attempted to monitor my UDP connections using `netstat -a`, but cannot seem to figure this out.

Note: I would like to use a log_address implementation, as I cannot install any third-party mods on the server to assist with the logging process.  I am also aware of HLSW and am not looking for a client-side application such as this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's not answered anywhere that I can find. I'd rather not explain about UDP since that's been covered over and over. However, if you have properly given the server your public IP address and the same port you're listening to with UDP and you're not getting any data, there is one trick to actually receiving packets.

You have to send a message to the server, on the server's standard gameplay port. It doesn't matter what it is, it can be 'hello' for all the server cares. After that you should start getting data from the server. I'm not sure exactly why this is, but it's probably a strategy by Valve to avoid their server spamming just any old IP.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to the [Steam HLDS Log Parser](https://github.com/tomav/steam_hlds_log_parser) gem.

It's in Ruby and works like that :

- on your hlds, use `logaddress xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx yyyy` where `x` is the ip and `y` your port where the logs will be sent using UDP
- get the gem, and check the example : it receives and parses the logs, and display content.

When i say `display`, in fact you can do what you want with the returned content (push to irc, write in a database...). Just write your own "displayer"

I published this gem few days ago, feel free to try and contribute.
I recently added i18n support with english and french translations.

Regards.

Comment: You can find code documentation here : http://rubydoc.info/gems/steam_hlds_log_parser